# Are overlays / modal alerts that display on site load accessible?

Tags: usability, accessibility, lightbox, overlay, modal-windows

Some websites welcome you with a Cookie Disclaimer or to Join their Social Page. You'll find a big modal window, mostly in center overlay rest of the site. (as an example: http://www.lynda.com/)

Whether using these models locks our keyboards or tabs? How do assistive technologies such as screen readers respond to this?

Comment: "snippets" == "cookies"?

Comment: Are [overlays outdated](http://sideproject.io/outdated-ux-patterns/)?

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer this question in two parts.

### **Are modal windows Accessible**

The answer to what I can find seems to be **Generally no**. I recommend looking at this study which was done to check how screen readers react to modal windows. To [quote the study](http://zufelt.ca/blog/can-modal-dialog-be-made-work-properly-screen-reader-users-web)

> Being a screen-reader user I tested several modal dialogs, including
>   the jQuery modal dialog, with several screen-reader / browser
>   combinations. In short, the user experience was unpredictable and
>   ranged from the existence of the dialog not being reasonably
>   perceivable to the user, to not all of the content in the dialog being
>   perceivable to the user. It is important to note that best practices
>   have been developed explaining how to create an accessible modal
>   dialog, however it would appear that even when following these
>   practices modal dialogs cannot be made accessible for screen-reader
>   users.

The results of the testing are given below

> ### **Results of Testing**
>
> **Firefox 3.6 and JAWS 11**
>
> When activating the modal dialog nothing appeared to happen. Once I
>   refreshed the JAWS virtual buffer and navigated to the bottom of the
>   page I was able to find the dialog. The dialog was "modal" to the
>   extent that I could not activate links on the underlying page,
>   however, there was no indication that the links were disabled, they
>   just simply didn't work.
>
> **Firefox 3.6 and NVDA 2009.1**
>
> When activating the modal dialog NVDA announced the title of the
>   dialog. I was unable to navigate the content of the dialog with the
>   standard NVDA reading keys. When I pressed tab NVDA announced the
>   Close button. I was still unable to access any of the other content in
>   the dialog. The dialog was "modal", I was unable to interact with the
>   underlying page, including not being able to read any of the content
>   from the underlying page.
>
> **Safari 4.0.4 and VoiceOver (OS X 10.6.2)**
>
> When activating the modal dialog nothing appeared to happen. When I
>   navigated to the bottom of the page I found the dialog. The dialog was
>   "modal" to the extent that I could not activate links on the
>   underlying page, however, there was no indication that the links were
>   disabled, they just simply didn't work.
>
> The problems identified in testing modal dialogs with screen-readers
>   can be broken down into two general groups. 1. Problem with perceiving
>   the existence of a dialog, and 2. problem with accessing the content
>   within the dialog, separate from the content of the underlying
>   page.The results of the testing are detailed below

### **Can Modal windows be made accessible**

Yes but there are [specific W3C guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#modal_dialog) which must be followed to make it accessible.To summarize the reference

- The first focusable item in the modal dialog should receive the keyboard focus.
- The window behind the modal dialog should not be allowed to be clicked on
- The modal dialog must trap the keyboard focus inside the modal dialog so the user can’t accidentally interact with the window behind the modal dialog.
- When the user is on the last focusable item and presses Tab, the user should be taken to the first focusable item in the modal dialog.
- When the user is on the first  focusable item and presses Shift-Tab, the user should be taken to the last focusable item in the modal dialog.
- The position of the keyboard focus before the modal window opens must be saved, and the focus must be restored to this location after the modal dialog closes.

I recommend looking at these links for additional information on how to make a modal window or overlay accessible

[The Incredible Accessible Modal Window, Version 1](http://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/training/aria/modal-window/)

[Incredible Accessible Modal Window, Version 2](http://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/blog/2014/01/02/incredible-accessible-modal-window-version-2/)

[Is there a way to do one accessible modal? (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016433/is-there-a-way-to-do-one-accessible-modal)